# My Application should connect to Exchange Server 2013 set OOF for users on vacation

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am coding an C# app that should connect to Exchange Server 2013 on-premise (Servers Location is not in our Company). I`ve got an account (User and Pass) with readonly admin-rights for now and want to read and set OutOfOffice Objects for other users. I decide to use EWS Managed API over Autodiscovery but I am bit confuse how.

I tried to connect with "service.UseDefaultCredentials = true" and read contacts -> this works.

```
        try
        {
            ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("service.exchange", "1234", "domain");
            _service.TraceEnabled = true;
            _service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

            _service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            _service.AutodiscoverUrl("user2@domain.net", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            foreach (Contact contact in _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, new ItemView(2)))
            {
                var test = contact;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
```

After that I tried the same with _service.UseDefaultCredentials = false; got error -> "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located." I am not shure if this "direct log on" is the right way, On msdn I've read about "delegate access" and "Impersonation" (NTLM and Basic Authentication) I'am a bit confused. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi Mikro, Is the service account in the same organization as user2@domain.net you are trying to AutoDiscover?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Venkat. I think so, because I've got this user from our IT-Admin in my Company. Thank you for help

Comment: Hi Guys,

I was able to connect via Impersonation for now. I don`t know if it`s the correct way but it works. Need to read more about the consequences. (Also it`s important that the Service account have the correct role -> ApplicationImpersonation)


Regards